# Output of Stored Proc in Logic apps not becoming Dynamic content

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've made a Stored Proc and I've initialized it in a variable and am trying to make the output of the Stored Proc Dynamic content in Logic Apps, however. Once I put the variable in the Parse JSON step, it will not become Dynamic. Any advice on how to make my Stored Proc output Dynamic content?

My output varies on the number of entries I'm able to retrieve and I think that's my issue. I've set my Parse JSON scheme to look for 6 entries and sometimes I will get 8-10, which I believe is my problem How can I make it so that no matter how many entries come through from my Stored Proc, I can capture those values in dynamic content and use them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to check the SQL dynamic content rather than checking the Parse JSON Connector. Make sure you are checking in the dynamic content of Parse JSON.

[image]

Also, after reproducing from my end, I could able to get the expected results without using Parse Json too.

[image]

when you follow the above the process you can retrieve no matter how many entries are there in the table. Below is the complete flow that worked for me.

[image]

Below is the schema of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[proc1]'))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "OutputParameters": {
                                "properties": {},
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "ResultSets": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "Table1": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "firstname": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "lastname": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "firstname",
                                                "lastname"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "ReturnCode": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've done what you suggested, but I do not get the fields dynamically from the "Execute Stored Proc" step. I just get Body, Output Parameters, Resultsets, and ReturnCode. I wonder if it has something to do with the actual stored proc itself?

Comment: Okay, so now its working! Thank you. The above suggestion was what I needed to do using the Stored Proc and Parse JSON